# Keyboard layout changes with each application

Tags: keyboard, remapping, editor

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and for some reason my keyboard layout changes with each application.  If I start  terminal, I get what I expect and it works correctly, however if I type something in the editor of "Texmaker" it changes, or if I go to type something in an email as in the editor for "Thunderbird" it changes to something different again.

Any suggestions on how to lock them all to the same layout as is chosen by the terminal would be most welcome.

Comment: By default, keyboard layout does not change out of itself. Please provide details: what keyboard layout do you use, which do you have installed and provide examples where the keys change.

Comment: I didnbt' think so either, but ....  key two rows up from bottom, two in, next to left shift key, in terminal get \ but in texmaker or thunderbird editor, or this editor get <.  Shifted 3 key, on terminal get £ but in Thunderbird get #.  I can give more examples if you need.  This is the same user on the same instance of Ubuntu all at the same time.

Comment: Add any information useful for the question to your question itself, not to comments, i.e., use "edit".

Comment: Do you have anything positive to contribute about the subject of the question?  Kinda like the spirit of Stackoverflow?

Comment: Yes I have. I think it is a constructive suggestion for you to add specific information to the question itself rather than in a comment, so future readers immediately have all relevant information without having to read the comments (which are not permanent). Mentioning your specific keyboard layout can stimulate someone with the same layout to effectively check on their system. This further increases the chance of getting help.